# How to mock methods with functional interface parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In Mockito, how can I mock a method that takes a functional interface as a method parameter? For example:

`String foo(String m, Function<Double, Options> r) {}`

Comment: If you call a void method on a mocked object, by definition it does nothing, as it returns nothing.

Comment: How would you do if it returns a value?

Comment: Expect an any() object and return whatever you want.

Comment: Like you would mock any other method? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 6):

Below has not been compile-tested/run, might have minor errors.  I know it has warnings for the generic

```
class Foo {
    String foo(String m, Function<Double, Options> r) {}
}

class Bar {
    Foo myFoo; // assume this is normally injected or something

    boolean works() {
        // ... code that somehow uses myFoo and processes the String returned
    }
}

class BarTestCase {
    @Mock private Foo foo;
    @InjectMocks private Bar bar

    @Test
    public void testFooMethod() {
        when(foo.foo(anyString(), any(Function.class)).thenReturn("ABCD1234");
        assertTrue(bar.works());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your functional interface is in a method of a class that is mocked:

```
Mockito.when(mockedClass.methodName(signature with Mockito)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

This would save time to mock objects rather than functional interface.

Comment: FYI: in English, sentences end with a single dot . not two. Please don't add double dots at the end of every sentence you write, as that makes it more difficult to read.